# not able add a class to a worker role?

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2012, owin

I'm going through the following tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/host-aspnet-web-api-in-an-azure-worker-role

Under the section for "Configure Web API for Self-Host" there's a screenshot to right-click the worker role then Add > Class ...

However, when I try to do this in my local environment, I don't have the option to Add a Class. The context menu only displays the following items:

New from Template
New Item...
Existing Item...
New Folder

Any idea why I'm not able to Add a Class to my Worker Role as described in the tutorial?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what your instance looks like (to compare against the documentation you linked to)?

Comment: Here's a screenshot the context menu I get in my dev environment:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nlnjxwedqghgwd/context%20menu%20-%20add%20class%20-%20not%20available.png?dl=0

"Add Class..." is not available as a second-level option through these menu items.

Comment: You are right-clicking on the wrong thing. You need to add the class to the actual project, not the worker role node under the azure project.